# Groupby and resample on time series data

Tags: python, pandas

**Data:**

```
ohlc_dict = {
'Open':'first',
'High':'max',
'Low':'min',
'Last': 'last',
'Volume': 'sum'}

data['hod'] = [r.hour for r in data.index]

data.head(10)
Out[61]:

                    Open    High    Low    Last    Volume   hod dow
Timestamp                           
2014-05-08 08:00:00 136.230 136.290 136.190 136.290 7077    8   Thursday
2014-05-08 08:15:00 136.290 136.300 136.240 136.250 3881    8   Thursday
2014-05-08 08:30:00 136.240 136.270 136.230 136.230 2540    8   Thursday
2014-05-08 08:45:00 136.230 136.260 136.230 136.250 2293    8   Thursday
2014-05-08 09:00:00 136.250 136.360 136.240 136.360 15014   9   Thursday
2014-05-08 09:15:00 136.350 136.360 136.260 136.270 11697   9   Thursday
2014-05-08 09:30:00 136.270 136.270 136.190 136.200 15600   9   Thursday
2014-05-08 09:45:00 136.200 136.270 136.200 136.240 9025    9   Thursday
2014-05-08 10:00:00 136.240 136.270 136.240 136.260 7128    10  Thursday
2014-05-08 10:15:00 136.250 136.260 136.200 136.200 6100    10  Thursday
```

**Question:**

Both of the following are changing the timeframe from 15 mins to a 1 hour interval:

**Approach 1:**

```
data['2016'].groupby('hod').Volume.mean().head()

hod
8     8452.597
9    16485.398
10   15619.626
11   14132.666
12   11470.058
Name: Volume, dtype: float64
```

**Approach 2:**

```
df_h1 = data.resample('1h').agg(ohlc_dict).dropna()
df_h1['hod'] = [r.hour for r in df_h1.index]
df_h1['2016'].groupby('hod')['Volume'].mean()

Timestamp
2014-05-08 08:00:00   15791.000
2014-05-08 09:00:00   51336.000
2014-05-08 10:00:00   28855.000
2014-05-08 11:00:00   56543.000
2014-05-08 12:00:00   25249.000
Name: Volume, dtype: float64
```

Only approach 2 gives what appears to be accurate output of the volume data.

How do I change approach 1 to give me the same `Volume` output as approach 2 but using `groupby` instead of `resample`?  I'm not sure how to use the `ohlc_dict` with approach 1 and feel this is what is required.

Comment: In *Approach 1* you are taking straight averages over all observations of that hour type.  *Approach 2* you are summing first (for `Volume`) across each hour, then taking the average of those sums across all hours.  I'd expect *Approach 2* to give results a multiple of times bigger than *Approach 1* where multiple is ~ the frequency of observations per hour.

Comment: hi @piRSquared thanks for your input, I suspected this, which is why I asked how to use the `ohlc_dict` with approach 1.  Is it possible?

Comment: @piRsquared (or anyone else interested).  I have cross referenced this data against a commercial charting package and approach 2 appears to be giving the correct output.  Would be useful to see how the  groupby (approach 1) syntax needs to be modified to get same results as approach 2.